# The plane of vectors $(b_1,b_2,b_3$) is not a subspace when $b_1=1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, intuition

So there was an exercise in Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra book in which you had to determine whether subsets were subspaces or not. In solutions, it was said that the plane of vectors $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ is not a subspace when $b_1=1$, since a subspace should contain $(0,0,0)$ vector. I'm not sure what's meant by plane of vectors, is it their linear combination?. Also i'm not sure what it means for a vector $b_1$ to be equal to $1$? Aren't $b_1,b_2,b_3$ just some vectors?

Maybe $b_1,b_2,b_3$ refer to the components of a vector? But then I'm not sure why, for example, $(b_1,b_2,b_3)=(1,0,0)$ wouldn't pass through the origin.

From what I gather, a linear subspace is just a linear combination of vectors and that it should always include $0$ vector. However, since we define the vectors  to always start at the origin, then linear combination of any vectors should always give a vector space, am I wrong?

Sorry if the question is ambiguous, I'll try to explain further if need be. I'm just having trouble understanding some of the key concepts.

EDIT: adding a picture so it's more clear what the author meant.

[image]

Comment: This is the plane $x=1$; think geometrically.

Comment: I think what is meant is the set of all vectors of the form $(1, b_2, b_3)$. Are you sure you have quoted the text literally, as the phraseology doesn't sound very natural to me.

Comment: "I'm not sure what's meant by plane of vectors" me neither. Are yo sure it's not "Gilbert Strang**e** Linear Algebra book"? Go and find a better book.

Comment: Well, first, I think the "plane of vectors" here is the usual 2D plane, as there are 3 parameters $b_1, b_2$, and $b_3$; when you fix $b_1 = 1$, the other 2 parameters can be any number, so it is on a plane

Comment: I've added a picture so you can see the exact phraseology

Comment: Why am I being downvoted? Please do explain if there's something wrong with my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect “the plane of vectors $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ with $b_2=0$” means $\{(b_1,b_2,b_3)\in\Bbb R^3: b_2=1\}$. Denote the latter set by $P$. Here $\Bbb R^3$ is considered as a vector space over $\Bbb R$, so the vectors are *elements* of $\Bbb R^3$. This vector space has a standard base consisting of vectors $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$, and $e_3=(0,0,1)$. Then any element $v=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ of $\Bbb R^3$ is also a linear combination $b_1e_1+b_2e_2+b_3e_3$ of vectors $e_1$, $e_2$, and $e_3$. Remark that the vector $v$ is a *point* $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ and so if we are very formal then we don’t say that $v$ passes through (or starts at) the origin $(0,0,0)$ of $\Bbb R^3$ (unless $v=(0,0,0)$). Now we see that the set $P$ of points is indeed a plane (orthogonal to $Oy$ axis). Since $P$ does not pass through the origin of $\Bbb R^3$, $P$ is a not a linear subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Alex thanks for responding. You say that the vector $v$ is a point $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ and that it doesn't pass through the origin. That's what confuses me, don't vectors, by our definition, start at the origin? It's the way vectors have been defined in this book from start and in every textbook I've come across. So does that mean that in this case the author means just a general vector with $b_1,b_2,b_3$ components, not the one that passes through the origin?

Comment: @Ebrin Yes, an abstract vector space is defined as a set of elements, not a set of directed segments strarted from an origin.